# Error on Access Import - Run-time error '3265': Item not found in this collection

Tags: xml, ms-access, vba, runtime-error

I have taken over an Access database created by someone else and I have little to no Access experience.  I am getting a `Run-time error '3265': Item not found in this collection.` error when I try to run the code which imports an xml file.  When I debug, line 4 of the below code is highlighted in yellow. Can you please provide any hints at what generally causes this?  This process is run everyday with a new holdings file, so we delete the previous day's Analytics table and create a new one.  Thanks in advance.

```
'import holdings file
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "ANALYTICS"
Application.ImportXML XmlHoldingsFile, acAppendData
CurrentDb.TableDefs("INSTRUMENT").Name = "ANALYTICS"
```

Comment: That error would happen if there is no table named *INSTRUMENT*.  Does it exist?

Comment: You are right.  Previously the file had always imported into a new table named "INSTRUMENT" but now for some reason the table is being named the same as the xml file name.  There are a lot of tables and so I didn't see this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever editing/deleting/re-creating objects across a collection like Access' Tabledefs, Forms, Querydefs, or Reports during an automation process, it is helpful to to loop through entire set to find needed object and conditionally edit or delete it.

This is similar to renaming or deleting a worksheet in an Excel workbook (loop through all worksheets and rename if such worksheet exists):

```
Dim db As Database
Dim tbldef As TableDef

Set db = CurrentDb

For each tbldef in db.TableDefs
  If tbldef.Name = "INSTRUMENT" Then
       tbldef.Name = "ANALYTICS"
  End if    
Next tbldef

' UNINITIALIZE OBJECTS
Set tbldef = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```